# Как сделать красивую сетку на Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html-canvas

Нужно нарисовать сетку на canvas тонкой линией.
Делаю пиксельарт canvas.

Я использую `ctx.lineWidth = 0.1;`, тогда сетка получается размытой. Размытость видна через лупу очень сильно
При добавлении смещения на `0.5px` при отрисовке сетки - всё становится неплохо, но она залезает своими краями на рисунок, и это проблема, потому что размер ячейки всего `5х5px`.

Что бы сетка не рисовалась поверх пикселя я решил сместить сам рисунок на `0.5px`. Получился обратный эффект - сетка чёткая и красивая, рисунок - размытый и не красивый.

Затем я решил, что проще будет нарисовать сетку в фотошопе, размером с холст (он фиксированного размера) и разместить сетку таким образом. Фотошоп категорически отказывается от рисования линий меньше `1px` (оно и понятно), но всё таки я решил посмотреть что будет. В итоге - мы получаем ровную сетку, ровное изображение, но при этом каждый из пикселей теперь не `5x5`, а `4х4` (кто бы мог подумать)

**Вопрос**: Каким образом отрисовать тонкую сетку с ячейкой `5x5px`, с самой минимальной толщиной линии, что бы при этом сетка была чёткой, и само изображение не искажалось?

Сетка без смещения:

[image: Сетка без смещения]

Сетка со смещением, изображение - без:

[image: Сетка со смещением, изображение - без]

Сетка и изображение со смещением:

[image: Сетка и изображение со смещением]

```js
// Canvas с сеткой без смещения
var canvas = document.getElementById('example1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Рисуем пиксели для наглядности
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillRect(20, 30, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 5, 5);
  
//Задаём толщину линии и цвет
ctx.lineWidth = 0.1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red"

// Рисуем вертикальные линии
for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += 5) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Рисуем горизонтальные линии
for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y += 5) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Canvas с сеткой со смещением в 0.5
var canvas = document.getElementById('example2');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Рисуем пиксели для наглядности
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillRect(20, 30, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 5, 5);
  
//Задаём толщину линии и цвет
ctx.lineWidth = 0.1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red"

// Рисуем вертикальные линии
for (var x = 0.5; x < canvas.width; x += 5) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Рисуем горизонтальные линии
for (var y = 0.5; y < canvas.height; y += 5) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Canvas с сеткой со смещением в 0.5
var canvas = document.getElementById('example3');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Рисуем пиксели для наглядности
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(20.5, 20.5, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillRect(20.5, 30.5, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillRect(30.5, 30.5, 5, 5);
  
//Задаём толщину линии и цвет
ctx.lineWidth = 0.1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red"

// Рисуем вертикальные линии
for (var x = 0.5; x < canvas.width; x += 5) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Рисуем горизонтальные линии
for (var y = 0.5; y < canvas.height; y += 5) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas{
background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<p>Canvas с сеткой без смещения</p>
<canvas id="example1" width="100" height="100"></canvas>

<p>Canvas с сеткой со смещением в 0.5</p>
<canvas id="example2" width="100" height="100"></canvas>

<p>Canvas с сеткой со смещением в 0.5 и смещением изображения</p>
<canvas id="example3" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно увеличить разрешение у canvas, сохранив при этом его размеры.
увеличиваем canvas, сохраняя размеры:

```
canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";
var scale = 2;
canvas.width = canvas.width * scale;
canvas.height = canvas.height * scale;
```

Меняем масштаб ctx, чтобы рисовать по тем же координатам

```
ctx.scale(scale, scale);
```

Весь код:

```js
// Canvas с сеткой без смещения
var canvas = document.getElementById('example1');
canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";
var scale = 2;
canvas.width = canvas.width * scale;
canvas.height = canvas.height * scale;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.scale(scale, scale);

//Рисуем пиксели для наглядности
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillRect(20, 30, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 5, 5);
  
//Задаём толщину линии и цвет
ctx.lineWidth = 0.1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red"

// Рисуем вертикальные линии
for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += 5) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Рисуем горизонтальные линии
for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y += 5) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Canvas с сеткой со смещением в 0.5
var canvas = document.getElementById('example2');
canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";
var scale = 2;
canvas.width = canvas.width * scale;
canvas.height = canvas.height * scale;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.scale(scale, scale);

//Рисуем пиксели для наглядности
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillRect(20, 30, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 5, 5);
  
//Задаём толщину линии и цвет
ctx.lineWidth = 0.1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red"

// Рисуем вертикальные линии
for (var x = 0.5; x < canvas.width; x += 5) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Рисуем горизонтальные линии
for (var y = 0.5; y < canvas.height; y += 5) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Canvas с сеткой со смещением в 0.5
var canvas = document.getElementById('example3');
canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";
var scale = 2;
canvas.width = canvas.width * scale;
canvas.height = canvas.height * scale;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.scale(scale, scale);

//Рисуем пиксели для наглядности
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(20.5, 20.5, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillRect(20.5, 30.5, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillRect(30.5, 30.5, 5, 5);
  
//Задаём толщину линии и цвет
ctx.lineWidth = 0.1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red"

// Рисуем вертикальные линии
for (var x = 0.5; x < canvas.width; x += 5) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Рисуем горизонтальные линии
for (var y = 0.5; y < canvas.height; y += 5) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<p>Canvas с сеткой без смещения</p>
<canvas id="example1" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>

<p>Canvas с сеткой со смещением в 0.5</p>
<canvas id="example2" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>

<p>Canvas с сеткой со смещением в 0.5 и смещением изображения</p>
<canvas id="example3" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло